# Why doesn't my RxJava timer application terminate?

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a simple application using RxJava 2:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

    final Observable<String> ticker = Observable.interval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .take(10)
        .subscribeOn(scheduler)
        .map(x -> x + "s");

    ticker.subscribe(x -> {
        System.out.println(x);
    });
}
```

It correctly prints the timer 10 times:

```
0s
1s
2s
3s
4s
5s
6s
7s
8s
9s
```

However, the application does no terminate after `9s`. It seems that there is some thread keeping it alive.

How should I implement this so that the application terminates after `ticker` completes?

Comment: You can terminate it by shutdown the `ExecutorService` on completed (not recommend)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not related to `RxJava` specifically , but to the `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`, by JVM specifications, the console app wil not exit until all non daemon threads are finished executing. (or explicitly call to `System.exit()`).
Now `newCachedThreadPool` executer keeps a threads in a cache for future use, and will close the threads only after 60 sec of no use (see docs), so what's happen here is that RxJava uses a thread from this cache and then after all items emitted, you need to wait 60 sec for the app to quit (juat run it and wait).

By the way, `interval()` acts by default on `computation` `Scheduler`, you can override it using overload that also gets `Scheduler` as a param.